# How to restrict Kafka Admin Client access control for granting acl permissions?

Tags: permissions, apache-kafka, acl

**Summary**

The main question is how does one secure the setting of of ACLs on Kafka. ACLs can be used to restrict who can consume / produce to topics, but how is the setting of ACLs restricted? E.g. some user on another network machine using `kafka-acls.sh`

**Details**

I am quite new to kafka and I've just setup up my first kafka 1.0.0 cluster and I am using the Kafka admin CLI(kafka-acls.sh) to grant acls for principals.

Here is problem I found: I can use this kafka-acls.sh on any other machine to manipulate my kafka cluster, without any permission required?! Is this an existing security issue?

My requirement is, as an admin, for my kafka topics I would grant read permission to the consumers. But if the consumer owners can use the kafka-acls.sh, they could add that permission by themselves.

I've tried these:

> kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --cluster --operation Create --deny-principal User:*
>
> kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --cluster --operation Alter--deny-principal User:*
>
> Current ACLs for resource `Cluster:kafka-cluster`:
>
> User:* has Deny permission for operations: Create from hosts: *
> User:* has Deny permission for operations: Alter from hosts: *

I was hoping this can stop anyone to change ACLs on any topics; but I still can grant permission to any principal. I am expecting some settings in kafka properties file that can do the work. My properties settings regarding ACL are:

> # Switch to enable topic deletion or not, default value is false
> #delete.topic.enable=true
>
> ###To enable ZooKeeper authentication on brokers
> zookeeper.set.acl=true
>
> authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
>
> super.users=User:Admin

Any Ideas to restrict the admin CLI, guys?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACLs are stored in Zookeeper so you need to run Zookeeper in secure mode with authenticated access (requires Apache Kafka 0.9 or higher).

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-38%3A+ZooKeeper+Authentication

This will allow you to restrict the ACL admin tools from working anywhere and by anyone since they include a zookeeper client which will have to be configured with valid admin credentials in order to connect and change Kafka ACLs stored in Zookeeper.

There is an example secure Kafka broker and Zookeeper setup explained in this blog post 
https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/

In more recent versions of Apache Kafka there is also an API called AdminClient which allows apps to be written without direct Zookeeper dependency or connections. In 1.0.0 the AdminClient includes methods to create ACLs.

https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html

However at the moment the CLI commands in /bin have not been rewritten to use this new API which is why they still connect directly to Zookeeper.

Comment: H Hans, thanks for your reply. Agree with you on zookeeper acl authentication. Very helpful links.

Also my friend @acarlon referred this KIP https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-11+-+Authorization+Interface, which I think is equally important for me to understand the problem.

I also found this blog is quite helpful too:
https://ihong5.wordpress.com/tag/zookeeper-acl/

I am going to change my zookeeper's authentication and ACL.

Hope these discussion could help someone else as well.

Comment: Related to this , apart from acls. How to restrict client to create topics , but only using admin client. I am using  AWSMSK+Cert based authentication